# How inplace in mysql online DDL works?

Tags: mysql, database, ddl, alter, mysql-5.6

We know that in MySQL5.6 we have new type of algorithm called inplace to alter the tables online i.e without locking the table for other operations (DML and DDL).

In algorith = COPY we know that it creates a new table and copy all the data there and rebuild everything.
But whats INPLACE actually do ? Any idea or document ?

Comment: do you mean the manual page on it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html) ?

Comment: no, i mean how inplace algorithm works..
in this document there is nothing about the working of this algorithm.

Comment: Well it is open source. Were you expecting a thesis from someone?

Comment: No thesis just the difference in COPY algorithm and INPLACE algorith..